# How to see failed requests post parameters at Azure api management?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-oms

We are debugging our systems to see failed azure posts and want to learn why they failed in the first place.

The AzureMetric and Azure diagnostics are not helping when we are running the query over OMS.

***Where do we see which values made us fail ?***

**Our OMS Query**

search *
| where Resource == "xxx-API-NONPRODUCTION"
| where Type == "AzureDiagnostics"

**Sample Error from OMS**

$table
AzureDiagnostics
TenantId
yyy-0a7b-4833-8fb6-yyy
SourceSystem
Azure
TimeGenerated [UTC]
2017-12-20T15:05:00.845Z
Type
AzureDiagnostics
Environment_s
PROD
lastError_source_s
configuration
lastError_reason_s
OperationNotFound
lastError_message_s
Unable to match incoming request to an operation.
lastError_section_s
backend
OperationName
Microsoft.ApiManagement/GatewayLogs
Category
GatewayLogs
CallerIPAddress
51.yyy.34.yyy
location_s
UK West
method_s
GET
url_s
https://xxx-api-nonproduction.azure-api.net/qa/user/api/zzz/UserAccountExistsByEmailAddressAndIsEnabled/2bdel.qags2012@yopmail.com
cache_s
none
apiId_s
tttt
productId_s
tttt
userId_s
1
apimSubscriptionId_s
vvvv
ResourceId
/SUBSCRIPTIONS/vvvv-2F08-4DED-92B8-vvvv/RESOURCEGROUPS/xxx-CORE-NONPRODUCTION/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.APIMANAGEMENT/SERVICE/xxx-API-NONPRODUCTION
SubscriptionId
vvv-vvvv-vvv-vvv-vvv
ResourceGroup
xxx-CORE-NONPRODUCTION
ResourceProvider
MICROSOFT.APIMANAGEMENT
Resource
uuuu-API-NONPRODUCTION
ResourceType
SERVICE
CorrelationId
vvv-vvv-vvv-vvv-vvvvv
isRequestSuccess_b
false
Level_d
4
EventId_d
222
DurationMs
0
responseCode_d
404
responseSize_d
130

Answer (score 1):

By default API management service does not log request body or headers, that can be done but with some extra work. You'll have to use log-to-eventhub policy to send body into eventhub and read it there later to log. Or you could save request body into a variable and return it as a response bidy from on-error section when request fails.

But from your log I can see that you get OperationNotFound: Unable to match incoming request to an operation. That means that URL was called on APIM service that didn't match any operation defined in API. The URL in question is  https://xxx-api-nonproduction.azure-api.net/qa/user/api/zzz/UserAccountExistsByEmailAddressAndIsEnabled/2bdel.qags2012@yopmail.com

If we assume that "qa/user" is API suffix, then "/zzz/UserAccountExistsByEmailAddressAndIsEnabled/2bdel.qags2012@yopmail.com" should match URL template of one of operations in such API, and such operation must have method set as GET since that's what is being called.